# Create new text files from a unique Large List object in R

Tags: r, large-data, write.table

I have an object Large List type with 3 subgroups:

[Large List Object with the 3 subgroups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhlrv.png)

I want to create new text files for each subgroup. I mean, I want a new text file  per subgroup. If I have 3 subgroups, I want 3 different text files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
# define a list
mylist <- list(A = 1:10, B = 1:100, C = data.frame(X = 1:2,Y = c("A","B")))

# you can subset a list like this
mylist[[1]]
mylist[[2]]
mylist[[3]]

# write data to files
for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
  write.csv(mylist[[i]], paste0("testfile_",i))
}
```